# How to display the user who posted info in firebase

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am creating a marketplace app but, its only displaying my profile pic when I used another account to post this listing, all the listings only display the current user pic and username, I think the problem is currentUser since I don't want to display the current user information, I want to display the user who posted information.
here is my code

```
class _ProductDetailsState extends State<ProductDetails> {
  GlobalKey previewContainer = new GlobalKey();
  ScrollController _scrollController;
  var top = 0.0;
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  String _uid;
  String _name;

  String _userImageUrl;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollController = ScrollController();
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
    getData();
  }

  void getData() async {
    User user = _auth.currentUser;
    _uid = user.uid;


    final DocumentSnapshot userDoc = user.isAnonymous
        ? null
        : await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(_uid).get();
  {
      setState(() {
        _name = userDoc.get('name');
  
        _userImageUrl = userDoc.get('imageUrl');
      });
    }
    // print("name $_name");
  }
```

but this only prints my current user into, not the user who posted the item.

Comment: A simple idea would be to store the user info as 'postedBy' field in the posted object itself while the post was created. This will enable you to get the user who posted like `userDoc.get('postedBy')`

Comment: This [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62816207/retrieving-users-displayname-and-profile-picture-from-firebase) will help you get an idea on how to  list the details of a user who posts the info on firebase.

Comment: @Just Cai Did you manage to have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62816207/retrieving-users-displayname-and-profile-picture-from-firebase)? Was your issue resolved?